# MY emails from my domain going to spam

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

I verified my email its all good, but don't know the reason why emails from my domain going to spam

I checked content detective and email subject everything.

Comment: Is it possible, you started with a huge amount of emails right away, without ip warming (gradually increasing send volume)? IP warming is important to build a good sender reputation.

Comment: Is this going into spam on multiple email accounts, or just a single one?

Comment: all google,yahoo and hotmail

Comment: Hey @arjun is your marketing cloud account has Sender Authentication Package enabled

Comment: @Josyula How to check Sender Authentication Package is enabled or not.Please let me know.

Comment: @arjun you have open case with support and confirm whether its enabled in your account or not